Error when extracting text from PDF "?Identity-H Unimplemented?"
I am encountering an issue when attempting to extract text from a PDF file. Specifically, I receive the following error message:
?Identity-H Unimplemented?

This error only occurs with certain PDF files, and from what I understand, it is related to the fonts that the extraction process is unable to recognize.
use lopdf::Document;
use std::error::Error;

fn extract_text_from_pdf(file_path: &str) -> Result<String, Box<dyn Error>> {
    let doc = Document::load(file_path)?;
    let total_pages = doc.get_pages().len() as u32;
    let mut extracted_text = String::new();


    for page_number in 1..=total_pages {
        let page_text = doc.extract_text(&[page_number])?;
        let cleaned_text = page_text.replace(&format!("Page {}", page_number), "");
        extracted_text.push_str(&cleaned_text);
    }

    Ok(extracted_text)
}

fn main() {
    let file_path = "src/data/temp_storage/DAN.pdf";

    match extract_text_from_pdf(file_path) {
        Ok(text) => {
            println!("Extracted text: {}", text);
        },
        Err(e) => {
            eprintln!("Failed to extract text: {:?}", e);
        }
    }
}

Is there a way to solve this problem, or is there a better way to extract text from PDFs?

"This error only occurs with certain PDF files" - in that case you should probably add a link of such a PDF to allow people to reproduce the issue.

The PDF's contains a little bit of sensitive data, so i would prefer not to share it. But i think i will look at some other libraries/crates/tools. Thank you for you answer!
